# Compute (Co)Variance of Random Variable(s) Directly

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Is there a direct command in Mathematica that computes the covariance between two random variables?

Hence, instead of typing

```
Expectation[f(x)*g(y),{y~some distribution,x~some distribution}] - 
Expectation[f(x),{y~some distribution,x~some distribution}]*
Expectation[g(y),{y~some distribution,x~some distribution}]
```

Is there a command that archieves the same by typing simply

```
Covariance[{f(x),g(y)},{y~some distribution,x~some distribution}]
```

I have tried to use the following function:

```
CoVar[RVfuncs_, dist_] := 
Expectation[RVfuncs[[1]]*RVfuncs[[2]], 
dist] - (Expectation[RVfuncs[[1]], dist]*Expectation[RVfuncs[[2]], dist])
```

It works, but it is much slower than writing out the three "Expectation" parts.

Comment: The covariance between 2 random variables whose distributions are specified as in your examples will always be 0. You need to specify a multivariate distribution, such as `Covariance[BinormalDistribution[{m1, m2}, {sd1, sd2}, corr], 1, 2]`

Comment: How about the case x = y

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you tell Mathematica that `{x~someDist, y~someDist}`, it assumes they are independent, so unless someDist is a delta, you don't get x=y, and in such case I would think the covariance is indeterminate

Comment: About your edit and your `CoVar` function, what exactly is slower?

Comment: Ok thanks I see your point. I will rephrase the question